# Editing T4 poco template to implement custom interface

Tags: templates, interface, entity-framework-4, poco, t4

I am using the Poco generator with EF4 and I am wondering if it is possible to edit the T4 template to force all of my entity classes to implement a custom interface. Since the pocos get blown away and recreated each time the custom tool is run, I would have to add this upon each update - I would sure like to avoid that.

I realize I could create partial classes for each poco and implement the interface there, but I was hoping to avoid all that boilerplate code.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

I think I am getting closer to a solution. I am editing the tt template by adding the implemenatation to the signature that is generated.

<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class  <#=code.Escape(entity)#> : IEntity<#=code.StringBefore(" , ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>

But I have hit a bit of a snag. Some of my entities have base classes  (table inheritance) that I designated in the edmx design. I have need to force all the entities to implement an interface called IEntity. The IEntity contract has no methods so there really is nothing to implement. I will need to rely on all of the entities having a common base. This is due to a completely separate implementation of a custom validation framework. I am getting the proper signatures for most of the entities, however, the entities that already have a base class are throwing a wobbly because you cant implement an interface before you inherit a base class. :IEntity, BaseClass is not allowed. I need to swap those but am not sure how I would pull that off in the template.

Answer (score 2):

On perusing the code in the CodeGenerationTools class that the T4 template uses (found in the include file `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude`), I came across this function `StringAfter(string value, string append)`.  Therefore, the answer is quite simple, since you state all your entities have to implement `IEntity`, the following should do the trick:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#> : <#=code.StringAfter(code.Escape(entity.BaseType), "," )#> IEntity
```

In fact, I know it does because I've tested it :-)

Answer (score 0):

After the T4 template is added to your application, it becomes part of your app and as any other part of the app, you can do whatever you want with it. If for some reason, you don't want to modify the VS added template, make a copy of it and update this to include only the interface implementation. The second way would produce another set of partial files with the custom interface being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is near what you need but....
I´ve created a Nuget Package that scaffold tiers from T4-templates.
There are default templates for all interfaces (Repository Pattern and UnitOfWork), but you can edit these templates yourself and re-scaffold your system.

To keep it short.. You just install the package (Install-Package CodePlanner) and then define your domainmodel.. And then run "Scaffold CodePlanner.ScaffoldAll"

Its open source (codeplanner.codeplex.com)

Demo: http://average-uffe.blogspot.com/2011/11/codeplanner-011-released-on-nuget-and.html

Edit: The codeplanner package is built for MVC3!

Regards
Uffe